# Get email folders statistics from Microsoft Exchange Server 15

Tags: outlook, microsoft-exchange

We use a shared Outlook directory as our helpdesk. Emails come in, we allocate an email to a specific team member using categories, and then that person responds. Once an email issue is resolved it is moved to another shared directory called Done.

**My ultimate goal:**  Create a chart that shows

- How many emails were received,
- How many emails were sent,  and
- How many emails a team member sent.

I know how to create the chart using HTML/JavaScript, but I need this Outlook information in a CSV/JSON format to do this. I do not mind having to manually export data from Outlook into this format.

I do NOT need to know:

- subject of email
- recipients of email,
- contents of email

What is the best solution here?

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the [ReliefJet Essentials for Outlook](https://www.ReliefJet.com/Essentials) developed by my company. It provides a [comprehensive set of reports](https://www.ReliefJet.com/Essentials/Features#Reports) that will surely let you achieve your goals. You can get all required tables and create charts in Excel.

In particular, the "Message Statistics by ..." group of reports included in the product will give you all required data for building chart.

For example, Message Statistics by Date:

[image]

... and you can easily buld any charts available in Excel:

[image]